# PHP: Trouble with autoloading

Tags: php, apache, oop, autoload

I am creating a website and I am using Apache as my webserver.

I have created a website without the use of classes. All of my functions are located in one file and I just include this file on every page where I need to use some of the functions.

I am now wanting to swap to an OOP approach but I am having trouble understanding how to autoload my classes. I have been through a number of related pages, such as; [PSR-4 Example](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/), [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312688/php-class-autoloading) and I just can't seem to get my head around this.

So, as I am using Apache, the path for the root of my website is **C:\Apache\htdocs**.

My directories look as follows;

```
+ htdocs
    + Lib
        + Base
            - User.php
            - Device.php
            - Company.php
            - Database.php
        + Services
            - UserService.php
            - DeviceService.php
            - CompanyServer.php
        + Config
            - DbConfig.php
```

As an example so you can help me get my head around this, we will just talk about two classes **DbConfig** and **Database**.

**DbConfig.php** (with connection details omitted)

```
<?PHP
namespace Lib\Config;

class DbConfig
{
    protected $serverName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;

   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->serverName = 'not my server name';
        $this->userName = 'not my username';
        $this->passCode = 'not my password';
        $this->dbName = 'not my database';
    }
}
```

**Database.php** (Very simple until I can actually use it - at which point I will add its functionality)

```
<?PHP
namespace Lib\Base;

use Lib\Config\DbConfig;

class Database extends DbConfig
{
    protected $connection;
    private $dataSet;
    private $sqlQuery;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->dataSet = null;
        $this->sqlQuery = null;
    }
}
```

So..

1. How do I load these classes, using some implementation of **spl_autoload_register()**, into another *.php* file so that I may use them to create objects? for example in a file named '**Testing.php**'
2. Previously I would parse a *.ini* file outside of the root of my folder to get the database connection details, should I do this with my new approach of having the connection details in the class **DbConfig**?

Comment: spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});    

1. Use this function to your .php file which is must load always.
2. Classname and filename should same, otherwise autoload will not find the class. example Testing.php has the class name testing. :)

Comment: an nicely phrased and structured php-question +1

Comment: If you're trying to comply with PSR-4, why not use the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) autoloader?

Comment: @JustinHoward I'll have a look but it's important for me that I understand what is happening.

Comment: At this stage you don't seem to need PSR-4 compatibility, so just use a custom autoloader as @Desert_King suggests. If you do want a formal PSR-4 autoloader, check out [Zero to PSR-4 in 60 seconds](http://cerebriform.blogspot.com/2015/01/psr-4-in-60-seconds.html).

Comment: @AskMeOnce i create simple autoload example, understand for you. please check this https://github.com/rahul689/php-simple-autoload-example.git

Comment: @Desert_King thank you for the example code, I have it working now and I'm grateful for the extra effort.

Comment: @AskMeOnce  always welcome :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PSR-4 standard,

> The fully qualified class name MUST have a top-level namespace name, also known as a "vendor namespace".

Your classes don't seem to have this. To add it, change `namespace Lib\Config;` to, for example, `namespace AskMeOnce\Lib\Config;`. You'll need to add this prefix to all your classes.

Then, using the PSR-4 Autoloader you referenced, change `$prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';` to `$prefix = 'AskMeOnce\\';` and `$base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';` to `$base_dir = 'C:\Apache\htdocs';`. Put that function in a file called autoload.php, and require it in any file that needs to know how to autoload.

Once you `require` that autoloader, PHP will know to look for any class that begins with the namespace `AskMeOnce` in the specified base directory. After removing that prefix from the namespace, the namespace represents the rest of the path. For example, `AskMeOnce\Lib\Config\DbConfig` Will be looked for at `<basedir>/Lib/Config/DbConfig.php`.

To answer your questions specifically, (1) Just put the function in `autoload.php`, with the modifications I mentioned above. And (2) since the ini file is not a PHP class, it doesn't matter where it is as long as your code knows how to find it (whether this is a hard-coded path or otherwise).

Comment: I thought my top-level namespace name was Lib as that was where I am keeping all of my classes... So does that mean that the "vendor namespace" isn't actually representative of a folder itself? If so, you have made me understand.

Comment: Ah. Your top level namespace could be `Lib`, but that is probably not a good top level namespace (because it's so generic). If you want to do it anyway, just set `$prefix='Lib\\';`. How about this? Make your top level namespace `AskMeOnce`. Replace `Lib\Config` with `AskMeOnce\Config`. Make your base dir `C:\Apache\htdocs\Lib\AskMeOnce` (Add the AskMeOnce folder). This way you can include other libs in the lib folder if you want. And the "vendor namespace" is representative of the "basedir". It does not get turned into a folder path the way the rest of the namespace does.

Comment: And this would mean that all I do is require the **autoloader.php** on the page I needed to use the classes (say _Testing.php_) which would be located at **C:\Apache\htdocs** ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. On any page you want to use a class, `require 'autoloader.php'`. `Foo\Testing.php` would be located at `C:\Apache\htdocs\Testing.php` If the "vendor namespace" is `Foo` and the basedir is `C:\Apache\htdocs`. Also, Surround stuff with backticks (\`) to make it look like code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example I knocked together:

Create a file called `autoloader.php`. This example was taken from [PSR-4 Examples](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/). Change `Acme` to your projects name.

This will allow you to use namespaces, so long as they are stored under `Lib/` and you add the namespaces to each file (as you're already doing).

```
<?php
/**
 * An example of a project-specific implementation.
 * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
 * @return void
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Acme\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/Lib/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';
    print $file;
    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

This uses [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to handle autoloading of dependencies/classes, and also allows for the use of PRS-4 namespaces.

Next, your `Database` class would be stored in `Lib/Base/Database.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Base;

class Database
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function allUsers()
    {
        /*
         * Query to fetch all users from the database
         */

        return [
            [
                'username' => 'Bob',
                'role' => 'member'
            ],
            [
                'username' => 'Joe',
                'role' => 'admin'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

And finally, your index page includes the `autoloader.php` script, which takes care of automatically included the classes.

```
<?php

require_once 'autoloader.php';

$config = require 'config.php';

try {
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$config['MYSQL']['DATABASE']};host={$config['MYSQL']['HOST']}",
                   $config['MYSQL']['USERNAME'], $config['MYSQL']['PASSWORD']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect to database ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$db = new \Acme\Database($dbc);
print_r($db->allUsers());
```

And finally, you asked about configuration files. I use a config file like so:

```
<?php

return [
    'MYSQL' => [
        'USERNAME' => 'root',
        'PASSWORD' => '',
        'DATABASE' => 'test',
        'HOST' => 'localhost'
    ]
];
```

Which allows you to include the config file with a simple:

```
$config = require 'config.php';
```

And access like so:

```
$config['MYSQL']['USERNAME'];
```

I pass the `\PDO` database connection as a dependency into the `Database` class as an example. This is called [Dependency Injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html).

Another example: `Lib/Services/UserService.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Services;

class UserService
{
    ...
}
```

You can now call this in code (provided the autoloader is included) like so:

```
$userService = new \Acme\Services\UserService;
```

I'd also recommend checking out [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md). Super helpful if you want to use public packages from [Packagist](http://packagist.org) and it's very easy to create your own. Supports PSR-* autoloading too (PSR4 being most common).

Comment: That won't work unless he moves all his classes to a folder called `classes`, which is probably not what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

register a autoload function:

add the code in any file could be included before you use other php library classes, for example in your project entry file.

```
defined('ROOT') or define('ROOT', 'C:/Apache/htdocs');
// define root directory
// or `defined('ROOT') or define('ROOT', __DIR__)` if
// the file is in the root directory

spl_autoload_register(function($name) {
    $file = ROOT . "/{$name}.php";
    if(!is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return include $file;
    }
}, false, true);
```

not recommend to use namespace if your project is not big enough, just use directory and file name to do it

Comment: That won't work with his directory structure above. Not all classes are in the htdocs folder.

Comment: if so,  you can try the directories in your autoload function